# Laravel cache store does not support tagging on production

Tags: laravel, redis

I've set `CACHE_DRIVER=redis` locally and on production in my `ENV` file. Locally I can use tags and I see the tags and their values showing up in the Redis database.

However if I deploy to production I get `cache store does not support tagging`. My server is deployed through Forge so it should have Redis set up. I've been using it for a few weeks with Redis as cache driver so I'm surprise that it's throwing the error now.

Comment: I'd start by inspecting the output of `config('cache')` in Tinker looking for unexpected values.

Comment: This solved it. There was another `CACHE_DRIVER` with value `file` all the way at the end of my `ENV` file...